# Transfering File from python server to android client

Tags: android, python-2.7, file-transfer

i have a python 2.7 server and an android application. what I do is: send a URL as a string to the server that convert it into a PDF file, then I want to send this file to my android app. The problem is in android app i think, I send file without problem from server but when I try to open it on android it is empty (0 byte file)...

Python Server code:

```
class ThreadedServer(object):
def __init__(self, host, port):
    self.host = host
    self.port = port
    self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    self.sock.bind((self.host, self.port))

def listen(self):
    self.sock.listen(5)
    while True:
        client, address = self.sock.accept()
        client.settimeout(60)
        threading.Thread(target = self.listenToClient,args = (client,address)).start()

def listenToClient(self, client, address):
    size = 1024

    try:
        data=client.recv(size)

        /*code to convert URL into PDF*/
        /*output file to send is out.pdf*/

        fl=open("out.pdf")
        print fl.name

        while True:
            chunk = file.read(fl)
            if not chunk:
                break

        client.sendall(chunk)            

    except Exception, e:
        print str(e)
        client.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ThreadedServer('',4095).listen()
```

Android Class transfer file:

```
public class Conversione extends AsyncTask<String, String, File> {

@Override
protected File doInBackground(String... params) {
    String s=params[0],fl=null;
    BufferedOutputStream scrivi=null;
    Socket ss;
    try {
        ss = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.8"),4095);
        scrivi = new BufferedOutputStream(ss.getOutputStream());
        scrivi.write(s.getBytes());
        scrivi.flush();

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/MyReader");
        if(!file.exists())
            file.mkdir();

        fl= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/MyReader/out.pdf";
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int lenght;
        InputStream is = ss.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(fl);

        while((lenght=is.read(buffer))>0){
            os.write(buffer,0,lenght);
        }

        os.close();
        ss.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    File f=new File(fl);
    return f;
}
}
```

I don't have idea why this doesn't work, someone can help me?

Comment: Urls cannot be converted to files. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: `file.mkdir();` Better: `if (!file.mkdir()) { log could not create dir; return null;}

Comment: What is file size of out.pdf in server? How many bytes are receivedby client?

Comment: `client.sendall(chunk) `. And if you placed that in the while loop? To send every chunk.

Comment: @greenapps I use pdfkit that convert URLs into pdf file and thanks for suggestion whit mkdir()...i don't know exactely how big could be the file, users can chose every link and convert it but in the client the file is every time 0 byte, I'll try to place client.sendall in a loop, but i think the problem is in the client side